# Dynamically bind the series in High-charts with a dictionary object

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, highcharts

I want to bind a Dictionary object to a highcharts component this is my Dictionary code:

```
  public IDictionary<string, SerieObject> GetChartsData()
    {
        Dictionary<string, SerieObject> chartobject = new Dictionary<string, SerieObject>();

        chartobject.Add("red", new SerieObject()
        {
            Data = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
        });

        chartobject.Add("green", new SerieObject()
        {
            Data = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
        });

        chartobject.Add("blue", new SerieObject()
        {
            Data = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
        });

        chartobject.Add("purple", new SerieObject()
        {
            Data = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
        });

        chartobject.Add("yellow", new SerieObject()
        {
            Data = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
        });

        chartobject.Add("gray", new SerieObject()
        {
            Data = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
        });

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SerieObject> item in chartobject)
        {
          //? 
        }

        return chartobject;
    }
```

On the highcharts documentation I see this:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
```

The expected output I want is this:

```
   series: [{
    name: 'red',
    data: [1, 2, 3]
}, {
    name: 'green',
    data: [1, 2, 3]
}, {
    name: 'blue',
    data: [1, 2, 3]
}]
```

I don't want it hard coded but I want a solution with a for loop have a look at the following pseudo code:

```
for( i = 0; i< (dictionaryobject); i++){
 series: [{
name: dicitionarynames(like purple, yellow etc),
data: the values from the colors; 
}   
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the JSON is coming like

```
result= [{"red":[1,2,3],"blue":[1,2,3],"yellow":[1,2,3]}]
```

then you can get keys in a array like, `var keys= Object.keys(result[0]);`

then, `var series=[]`,

```
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
   series.push({name:keys[i],data:result[0][keys[i]]});
```